# Is there a way to put a specific value instead of a value that is originally needed to be but is undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a variable a specific value, when a value originally wanted to put is undefined

Like this in shell script

`VALUE=${VALUE1:-0}`
This means, if there is no VALUE1, then VALUE = 0

How can I put a specific value instead of undefined?

```
data() {
    return {
      value1: 0,
      value2: process.env.VALUE2 | '', // If process.env.VALUE2 is undefined then make value2 ''
    }
},
```

Comment: `value2: process.env.VALUE2 || '' `

Comment: `value2: process.env.VALUE2 ?? ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `?` operator.

for example, you could check whether there is any value in `process.env.VALUE2` like the following:

`let variable = process.env.VALUE2 ? 'there is value' : 0`

Does `process.env.VALUE2` have value? If yes then assign `'there is value'` to `variable` else assign `0` to `variable`